# Disabling a button by grabbing ElementRef: angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to disable a button when it is clicked. By clicking I'm calling a function and I want to disable the button using that function. How can I access button's property with ElementRef and disable it? I'm not very familiar with how to use ElementRef.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you really wanted to disable the button via an ElementRef, you can use the [ViewChild](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-var.html) method to get a reference to your button and then set the button to disabled using its `nativeElement` property.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
             <button #myButton (click)="onClicked()">Click me!</button>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('myButton') button;

  onClicked() {
    this.button.nativeElement.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

---

However, [Angular2 recommends using ElementRef's as a last resort](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html). The same functionality you desire can be achieved through [property binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding).

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
             <button [disabled]="isDisabled" (click)="onClicked()">Click me!</button>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  private isDisabled = false;

  onClicked() {
    this.isDisabled = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: One more example:`<button #btn (click)="btn.disabled = true">Click me!</button>`

Comment: @Michael, thanks for the reply. For the property binding approach, I'm already doing something like [disabled]="!form.valid" ('[disabled]' is already busy checking for form validity, so I can't write another variable to with [disabled]. Let me know if you have any suggestion on this.

Comment: You can join multiple conditions with a logical AND/OR operator like so: `[disabled]="!form.valid || isDisabled"`.

Comment: Sure, that totally works! Another question, what if I want to disable this button when I'm running some other function in a totally separate component?

Comment: @SaranshAhlawat You'd have to use [component interaction](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child). There are numerous ways of handling this however and it would be better suited to its own question. If this answers your question, please mark the answer as accepted (green tick).