# unable to setAttribute disabled using renderer2 on angular material select

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-material2

I am not able to disable the select dropdown of angular material using the renderer2. Below is my code

Component.html

```
            <mat-select #exLoc (selectionChange)="someFun($event)" [(value)]="someVal">
              <mat-option aria-selected="true" [value]="locVal" *ngFor="let location of locations">{{location.LocationName}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
```

Component.ts

```
constructor(public renderer: Renderer2) {} 
@ViewChild('exLoc') exLoc: ElementRef;
functionToDisableDropDown() {
 this.renderer.setAttribute(this.exLoc, 'disabled', 'true');
}
```

Comment: Where and how do you call functionToDisableDropDown()

Comment: <mat-select [disabled]='isDropDownDisabled' ...> functionToDisableDropDown() { this.isDropDownDisabled = true;}

Comment: @Vijay Sankhat: Yes, eventually I ended up doing that only. But why this is not working is bothering me.

Comment: @Vega: Calling that function on click event on some other button. That method is getting called. I checked with a console.log

Comment: @RaviYadav Then please up-vote my comment

Comment: please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035620/disabling-a-button-by-grabbing-elementref-angular2

Comment: @RaviYadav I have updated my answer. Check that. Use `MatSelect` instead of `ElementRef`

Comment: use renderer in the directive not in the component

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way to do it is actually to use Renderer2.

disabled is a Property that is why it is not working with your code.

Correct code :

```
this.renderer.setProperty(this.exLoc, 'disabled', true);
this.renderer.setProperty(this.exLoc, 'disabled', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of `exLoc` from `ElementRef` to `MatSelect`

```
constructor(public renderer: Renderer2) {} 
@ViewChild('exLoc') exLoc: MatSelect;

functionToDisableDropDown() {
  // not sure why is this not working
  //this.renderer.setAttribute(this.exLoc, 'disabled', 'true');

  // without using renderer
  this.exLoc.disabled = true;
}
```

Working [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cs6hwm)

Comment: tried that, didn't work. I eventually added the [disabled] = "value" in html and setting it as true and false in .ts file instead of calling the renderer2 method to get the desired result. But I still can't understand why the above code doesn't work.

Comment: Is it working without using renderer like `this.exLoc.nativeElement.disabled = true;`

Comment: yes as i said, i got the desired result. But my question is why its not working with renderer2

Comment: This could be a bug with `Renderer2` which does not accept `MatSelect` as input.

Answer (score 0):

Use -> this.render.setProperty(this.exLoc.nativeElement, 'disabled', true);
The ".nativeElement

Comment: Please explain your answer and format the code using backticks so it's easier to understand and read.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO! Please edit the post and make code formatted in your answer. As it will justify your answer and gives a clear view of what you are trying to explain.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but the real problem is probably located into the fact that MatSelect is a custom element which doesn't really have a disabled attribute. MatSelect has probably its own manage of [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor). So if you want to disable a MatSelect element, you should have a reference to that component and use its own setDisabledState method (implemented from ControlValueAccessor Interface).

```
setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void
```

**Such as:**

```
 @ViewChild(MatSelect)
 private _myMatSelect: MatSelect;

 ...

 xxx() {
     this._myMatSelect.setDisabledState(true); // Should trigger the engine to disable your MatSelect element.
 }
```